# I'm trying to create a calculator but it won't give me any results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I'm trying to make a pretty basic multiplication calculator and for some reason it won't actually calculate any results. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'll attach screenshots of each part of my code that I have so far.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

(Also I'm not entirely sure how to post/attach my code in this post, I apologize!)

Comment: screenshots of source code? please post the calculator to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This is what I got what I input my code: http://jsfiddle.net/VyT9k/

Answer (score 5):

[I just made a Calculator for someone else on this site about 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049055/passing-an-anonymous-function-as-a-parameter-with-preset-parameter-values/23049179#23049179).

Here's my code

```
function Calculator(initialNum) {

  var result = 0;

  // private api
  function set(num) {
    return result = num || 0;
  }

  function add(num) {
    return set(result + num);
  }

  function subtract(num) {
    return set(result - num);
  }

  function divide(num) {
    if (num === 0) throw new Error("Cannot divide by zero");
    return set(result / num);
  }

  function multiply(num) {
    return set(result * num);
  }

  function value() {
    return result;
  }

  function clear() {
    return set(0);
  }

  // exports; public api
  this.add      = add;
  this.subtract = subtract;
  this.divide   = divide;
  this.multiply = multiply;
  this.value    = value;
  this.clear    = clear;

  // "magic" api
  this.valueOf = value;

  // init
  set(initialNum);
}
```

Usage

```
var a = new Calculator; // 0
a.add(5);               // 5
a.add(10);              // 15
a.divide(5);            // 3
a.multiply(3);          // 9
```

Calculators can work with each other too

```
var b = new Calculator(3);  // 3
b.add(3);               // 6
b.multiply(a);          // 54
b.clear();              // 0
+a;                     // 9
```

Comment: How would that calculator apply to the one I'm trying to write (ex. http://jsfiddle.net/VyT9k/)